# Parse unstructured text in python

Tags: python, parsing, pdf, text

Am new to python and am trying to read a PDF file to pull the `ID No.`. I have been successful so far to extract the text out of the PDF file using `pdfplumber`. Below is the code block:

```
import pdfplumber

with pdfplumber.open('ABC.pdf') as pdf_file:
    firstpage = pdf_file.pages[0]
    raw_text = firstpage.extract_text()
    print (raw_text)
```

Here is the text output:

```
Welcome to ABC
01 January, 1991
ID No. : 10101010
Welcome to your ABC portal. Learn
More text here..
Even more text here..
Mr Jane Doe
Jack & Jill Street Learn more about your
www.abc.com
....
....
....
```

However, am unable to find the optimum way to parse this unstructured text further. The final output am expecting to be is just the ID No. i.e. `10101010`. On a side note, the script would be using against fairly huge set of PDFs so performance would be of concern.

Comment: This query is just a function rolling into a program which is supposed to split huge PDF files which I found to be working well with python, hence the preference. Whats on your mind btw?

Comment: @LarsSkaug: Define "slow". The comment is rather general and opionated.

Comment: @NobleAbraham: As mentioned in my answer below, Scala might be worth a look for you. Python is great, but not for everything. If you're starting out anyway, why not take a look at Scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a regular expression:

```
import pdfplumber
import re

with pdfplumber.open('ABC.pdf') as pdf_file:
    firstpage = pdf_file.pages[0]
    raw_text = firstpage.extract_text()
    m = re.search(r'ID No\. : (\d+)', raw_text)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

Of course you'll have to iterate over *all* the PDF's contents - not just the first page! Also ask yourself if it's possible that there's more than one match per page. Anyway: you know the structure of the input better than I do (and we don't have access to the sample file), so I'll leave it as an exercise for you.

Comment: Something missing here, getting empty result.
No there won't be more than one match on the page.

Comment: Maybe `^ID No\.` (the anchor, that is) to speed things up a bit. +1.

Comment: Ah, works like a charm after switching to search instead of match. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the id number is always the same, I would try to find the location of it with the find-function. `position = raw_text.find('ID No. : ')`should return the position of the I in ID No. position + 9 should be the first digit of the id. When the number has always a length of 8 you could get it with `int(raw_text[position+9:position+17]`)

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Python and actually need to process serious amounts of data, I suggest that you look at Scala as an alternative.

For data processing in general, and regular expression matching in particular, the time it takes to get results is much reduced.

Here is an answer to your question in Scala instead of Python:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor

val fil = "ABC.pdf"

val textFromPage = (1 until (new PdfReader(fil)).getNumberOfPages).par.map(page => PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(new PdfReader(fil), page)).mkString

val r = "ID No\\. : (\\d+)".r

val res = for (m <- r.findAllMatchIn(textFromPage )) yield m.group(0)

res.foreach(println)
```